# How to make a solid state SPDT switch?

Tags: switches, analog, analog-switch, spdt

I'd like to make an analog SPDT switch along the same lines as FSA2259UMX or similar chips, but out of simple discrete components.  This is partly for learning, and partly because I'm redesigning a circuit that has a whole bunch of these, and wondering if something like a simple dual MOSFET (DMG1029 etc) would do the same job without using a tiny/hard to assemble/expensive part.  A bit later on I'd like to know how to build my own N:1 multiplexers for fairly large N values (100's) which might be just a cascade of SPDTs.

Some of the nice specs that purpose-built switch ICs give are: break-before-make; controlled slew rate; flat resistance over different voltages; and flat attenuation up to pretty high frequencies.  I don't especially care about any of these in my simple circuit; I'd like the off state to have reasonably low leakage, but that's about it.  The circuit can be make-before-break, it can be slow to switch, and it can have fairly high (and variable) resistance.  Making this out of a small number of common components is the trick.

I'm looking at signals around 0-3V and a logic level (3V) control input.  On-state resistance can be around 1-10 ohm (and may vary); off state leakage a few uA; and switching time in the 1us range.

Comment: Comparisons between different tech and without a target application circuit are pointless because you would need to specify the precise features and performances of item 1 that is relevant to the target to check whether item 2 is compatible/suitable.

Comment: please ask a question